# Adding SearchController to navigationItem causes status bar to change to black when active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This particular view is part of a UINavigationController, so the navigation bar is provided by that. I call the following code in `viewDidLoad()` of the presenting view controller.

```
func buildSearchBar() {
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30/255, green: 50/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30/255, green: 50/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Using interface builder, I set the same color for the navigation bar for the navigation controller.

When the search bar is active, the background of the status bar goes to black.

This is inactive.
[image: Inactive]

This is active.
[image: Active]

I have seen this problem on StackOverflow many times, and there has not been a solution that works. Seems like, for most people, it works out of the box once they set up the Search Controller. Most recent examples use similar code and don't mention having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used both iPhone and simulators in Xcode 10.1 and osx 10.14.1 and did not repeat the issue.

[image]

If you want to get the same color, just add `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

```
   func buildSearchBar() {
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30/255, green: 50/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30/255, green: 50/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

[image]

Comment: The status bar is still a different color than what the search bar background is... I haven't had time to try this but I think I need to make this particular screen separate from the global view controller I have set up.